# How to get string without accented character to match string with accented characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I need to be able to find accented strings like "Błachowicz", "Jędrzejczyk", "Bęben" with "Blachowicz", "Jedrzejczyk", "Beben"

The accents are from Polish language, the strings are in Mongo database.

I tried 
`db.fighters.find({ surname: { $regex: new RegExp(".*" + 'Blachowicz' + ".*", "i") } } )`
 but it doesn't work.

Comment: There's nothing built into JavaScript to do this. You'll need a library of some kind (recommendations for which are off-topic for SO). Or, of course, use character classes, e.g. `/B[ęe]ben/` or alternations if it's more complicated than that (as it is in German): `/B(?:ę|e)ben/` But presumably that gets complex fast.

Comment: I guess you may need to use a library like [Latinize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latinize) for this job. Well if you look at it's [code](https://github.com/dundalek/latinize/blob/master/latinize.js) you will see that it's just a huge look up object. You might even copy that too...

Comment: Thank for help guys, I ended up keeping both versions in database, with accents and without.